# Error: `of` no está definido

Tags: java

En el siguiente código:

```
Import.util.List;

List <Integer> numbers=List.of(2,4,5,6); // Aqui es donde me da el error
```

me marca el error:

> of is undefined

¿Cómo puedo arreglar este error de Stream?

Comment: Tienes que indicar en la declaración de que Clase son los elementos de la lista: `List <Integer> numbers=List.of(2,4,5,6);`

Comment: Hola Martin, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. No te olvides de completar el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general (y con ello ganarás una medalla). Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí tienes un error seguro y uno probable:

**Error seguro: La plantilla no está especializada**

```
List numbers
```

En Java es necesario indicar qué especialización de la plantilla va a ser `numbers`. El compilador no lo va a decidir por ti. Lo correcto sería poner:

```
List<Integer> numbers
```

**Error probable**

`List.of` solo está disponible a partir de Java 9. Para versiones anteriores tienes que utilizar `Arrays.asList()`:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 5, 6);
```

Comment: El **error probable** debería ser el **error seguro**. :)

Comment: @MrDave1999 java no es mi fuerte y no pretendía pasarme de listo jejeje

Answer (score 1):

En caso de que tu Java sea reciente, tu import está mal hecho.

```
Import.util.List;
```

debería de ser

```
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score -1):

En esa línea de código hay múltiples errores. El primero que viene a la mente es que List no es una clase en java, sino una interfaz. Y por tanto, no puede ser instanciado directamente. Luego, cuando se desea crear una lista, hay que dar el tipo de objecto parametrizado entre <>. Por ejemplo, List[String], o List[Integer] entre los símbolos mayor y menor, no entre corchetes como aquí.

Una vez declarada la lista hay que construirla, es decir, pedirle al sistema operativo que nos de la memoria necessaria para guardarla. Además, en este mismo paso, también le decimos al compilador de java la forma como deseamos que se materialice la lista. Hay dos formas, en una lista enlazada (en la que será fácil insertar en la mitad o borrar un elemento, o bien en un vector de posiciones contiguas, que será fácil de recorrer. En el ejemplo, uso la segunda opción, ArrayList, es decir, estoy diciendo quiero una lista que guardes en posiciones contíguas de memoria.

Y luego, añado los elementos.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();       
numbers.add(2);
numbers.add(4);
numbers.add(5);
numbers.add(6);
```

No sé de donde has sacado el método of(), porque no parece que exista. De todas formas, personalmente, me parece una buena propuesta que hacer a Oracle.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Basta una simple búsqueda en la API de Java para ver que [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) **si** existe

Comment: Pues sí. Gracias por la info, muy interesante. Yo lo miré usando el editor del netbeans, y no me apareció. Y no entiendo por qué :(

Comment: solo está disponible a partir de java9. Es probable que estés usando una versión anterior

Comment: Lo saque de un curso de codigofacilito de programacion funcional, gracias ya cheque lo de la API y efectivamente es por la verison de JDK que tengo instalada

Comment: ok gracias otra vez